# Распознавание объектов объектов на видео. Определять только класс "person" ghb

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, numpy, tensorflow

Мне необходимо определить на видео только людей, не могу разобраться что нужно изменить для этого. Программа определяет все объекты, если в NUM_CLASSES ставлю "1", то определяется только необходимый мне класс "person", но при этом так же выделяет объекты и присваивает им подпись "N\A". Прошу помощи. Использую следующий код для этого:

```
import numpy as np # Это расширение языка Python, добавляющее поддержку больших многомерных массивов и матриц, вместе с большой библиотекой высокоуровневых математических функций для операций с этими массивами.
import os # Модуль os предоставляет множество функций для работы с операционной системой, причём их поведение, как правило, не зависит от ОС, поэтому программы остаются переносимыми. Здесь будут приведены наиболее часто используемые из них.
import six.moves.urllib as urllib # Предназначен для поддержки кодовых баз, которые работают как на Python 2, так и на 3 без изменений
import sys # Модуль sys обеспечивает доступ к некоторым переменным и функциям, взаимодействующим с интерпретатором python.
import tarfile #Модуль позволяет считывать и записывать tar архивы.
import zipfile #Модуль позволяет считывать и записывать zip архивы.
from collections import defaultdict #предоставляет специализированные типы данных, на основе словарей, кортежей, множеств, списков.  defaultdict подкласса dict, который вызывает заводскую функцию для подачи отсутствующих значений
from io import StringIO # Модуль обеспечивает основные объекты языка Python для работы с различными типами ввода / вывода. Модуль StringIO позволяет работать со строкой как с файловым объектом. Все операции с файловым объектом производится в оперативной памяти. Для создания нового объекта предназначен класс StringIO. Формат конструктора 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt # Matplotlib — библиотека на языке программирования Python для визуализации данных двумерной (2D) графикой (3D графика также поддерживается). Получаемые изображения могут быть использованы в качестве иллюстраций в публикациях.
from PIL import Image #библиотека языка Python (версии 2), предназначенная для работы с растровой графикой.
from utils import label_map_util #взял из исходника папкой
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util
import tensorflow as tf # Это библиотека для глубинного обучения
import datetime 
import cv2 # Подгружаем OPENCV
import time

# # Подготовка модели
# Любая модель, экспортированная с помощью инструмента `export_inference_graph.py`, может быть загружена здесь просто путем изменения` PATH_TO_CKPT`, чтобы указать на новый .pb-файл.
# По умолчанию мы используем модель «SSD с Mobilenet». См. [Зонд зонирования для обнаружения] (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/object_detection/g3doc/detection_model_zoo.md) для списка других моделей, которые могут быть запущены из коробки с изменяя скорость и точность.


# Какую модель загрузить.
MODEL_NAME = 'ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco_2017_11_17' #Можно заменить на более новую  модель. Необходимо знать название файла.
MODEL_FILE = MODEL_NAME + '.tar.gz'
DOWNLOAD_BASE = 'http://download.tensorflow.org/models/object_detection/'


# Путь к замороженному графику обнаружения. Это фактическая модель, которая используется для обнаружения объекта.
PATH_TO_CKPT = MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'

# Список строк, которые используются для добавления правильной метки для каждого окна.
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join('data', 'mscoco_label_map.pbtxt')#отдельно запрашивается, должно находиться в папке программы в моем случае находиться в папке data.

NUM_CLASSES = 90 #Колличество используемых классов из mscoco_label_map.pbtxt. Если изменить на меньшее значение, то объекты которые не попали в список, будут определяться но подсвечиваться будут как N/A.
# ## Загрузить модель

if not os.path.exists(MODEL_NAME + '/frozen_inference_graph.pb'): #Проверяет наличие файла, Если нет файла то начинается загрузка модели
print ('Downloading the model') # прокси блокирует доступ к сайту загрузки. Нужно качать напрямую, через ссылку и название нужного пакета
opener = urllib.request.URLopener() # Модуль определяет функции и классы , которые помогают в открытии URL ( в основном HTTP)
opener.retrieve(DOWNLOAD_BASE + MODEL_FILE, MODEL_FILE)
tar_file = tarfile.open(MODEL_FILE) # Открывает архив
for file in tar_file.getmembers():  #Верните элементы архива в список TarInfo объектов. Список имеет тот же порядок, что и члены в архиве.
  file_name = os.path.basename(file.name) #os.path.basename(path) - базовое имя пути (эквивалентно os.path.split(path)[1]).file.name - возможно имя коренвого катлога в архиве
  if 'frozen_inference_graph.pb' in file_name: #Если есть файл frozen_inference_graph.pb в корневом катологе, то извлекает только его. 
   tar_file.extract(file, os.getcwd()) # Извлекает файл  в os.getcwd() - текущая рабочая директория.
print ('Download complete')
else:
print ('Model already exists')

# ## Загрузите (замороженную) модель Tensorflow в память.

detection_graph = tf.Graph()# Graph содержит набор tf.Operation объектов, которые представляют собой единицы вычисления; и tf.Tensorобъекты, которые представляют собой единицы данных, которые текут между операциями.
with detection_graph.as_default(): # Менеджер контекста, который переопределяет текущий график по умолчанию для времени жизни контекста:
od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef() #?????
with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid: # Возвращает режим, в котором файл был открыт.
    serialized_graph = fid.read() # Читает модель
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph) # GraphDef.ParseFromString()Метод (и, в общем, ParseFromString()способ по любому Protobuf обертку Python) ожидает строку в двоичном формате буфера протокола.
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='') # Импортирует граф из graph_def текущего значения по умолчанию Graph

# ## Загрузка карты ярлыков
# Ярлык отображает индексы категорий в имена категорий, так что, когда наша сеть сверток предсказывает «5», мы знаем, что это соответствует «самолету». Здесь мы используем внутренние функции утилиты, но все, что возвращает целые числа сопоставления словарям с соответствующими строковыми метками, будет прекрасным
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, 
max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

#Активировать устройство веб-камеры
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.mp4') # Видеозахват Выбераем веб камеру, если поставить значение 0 то будет выбрана фронтальная камера ноута или другие подключаемые элементы.
#total_frames = cap.get(7)
my_file=open('LOGFILE ' + datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S") + '.txt','w') #Открываем текстовый документ для записи данных
# Выполнение сеанса tensorflow
frames= []
with detection_graph.as_default():
with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
# Session Объект инкапсулирует среду , в которой Operation выполняются объекты и Tensorобъекты оцениваются. 
ret = True  # cap.read() в ret возвращает значение, типа Boolean 
(True/False). Если frame прочитан корректно: ret = True.
while (ret):
  # cap.set(1, 1000) 
   ret,image_np = cap.read()
   frames.append(image_np)
   if image_np is None:
        break
  # Развернуть размеры, так как модель ожидает, что изображения имеют форму: [1, None, None, 3]
   image_np_expanded = np.expand_dims(image_np, axis=0)
   image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
  # Каждый ящик представляет собой часть изображения, в котором был обнаружен определенный объект.
   boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')
  # Каждый балл представляет собой уровень уверенности для каждого из объектов.
  # Результат отображается на изображении результата вместе с меткой класса.
   scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
   classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')
   num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')
  # Фактическое обнаружение.
   (boxes, scores, classes, num_detections) = sess.run(
      [boxes, scores, classes, num_detections],
      feed_dict={image_tensor: image_np_expanded})
  # Визуализация результатов обнаружения.
   vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
      image_np,
      np.squeeze(boxes),
      np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
      np.squeeze(scores),
      category_index,
      use_normalized_coordinates=True,
      line_thickness=5) #Толщина линий рамки

   cnt = [category_index.get(value)for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5]
   cv2.putText(image_np,"Object detect= "+str(len(cnt)) ,(10,25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,0), 2)

   cv2.imshow('image',cv2.resize(image_np,(640,480)))       
   text_for_file = "Object detect= "+str(len(cnt))+'\n' + str()
   my_file.write(text_for_file)      
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        my_file.close()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        cap.release()
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вас устраивает скорость работы вашей модели, то самым простым вариантом будет отфильтровать результаты работы модели (`boxes`, `classes`, `scores`, `category_index`) таким образом, чтобы оставить только интересующие вас классы (`person` в вашем случае):

Упрощённый пример:

```
In [5]: category_index = [
   ...:     {'id':0, 'name':'tree'},
   ...:     {'id':1, 'name':'dog'},
   ...:     {'id':2, 'name':'cat'},
   ...:     {'id':3, 'name':'person'},
   ...:     {'id':4, 'name':'bus'}
   ...: ]
```

булевая маска, которая будет использоваться для фильтрования:

```
In [6]: mask = np.array([d['name']=='person' for d in category_index])

In [7]: mask
Out[7]: array([False, False, False,  True, False])
```

пример фильтрования:

```
In [8]: classes = np.arange(len(category_index))
```

Numpy матрицы можно фильтровать используя `"boolean indexing"`:

```
In [9]: classes
Out[9]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [10]: classes_flt = classes[mask]

In [11]: classes_flt
Out[11]: array([3])
```

`category_index` можно отфильтровать используя `list comprehension`:

```
In [12]: category_index_flt = [d for i,d in enumerate(category_index) if mask[i]]

In [13]: category_index_flt
Out[13]: [{'id': 3, 'name': 'person'}]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> Как посчитать количество "person" на изображении?

Пример (предположим что в данном примере код для класса `person` - `1.`):

```
In [18]: classes
Out[18]: array([[1., 2., 3., 4., 1., 2., 1.]])

In [19]: Scores
Out[19]: array([0.22801838, 0.52232889, 0.77384401, 0.87603768, 0.54693914, 0.51343637, 0.77768464])

In [20]: np.count_nonzero(np.where((Scores >= 0.5) & (classes == 1)))
Out[20]: 2
```

Comment: Сделал так.Не помогло. Также видет другие объекты другие объекты кроме person, выделяет и присваивает им N\A.
Возможно нужно что то изменить в блоке где происходит визуализация?

Comment: Подойду к вопросу по другому. Как посчитать количество "person"  на изображении?
Я использую следующий код в программе. который записывает информацию скадра в блокнот.Но он счетает все объекты, включая N\A.
cnt = [category_index.get(value)for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5]
text_for_file = "Object detect= "+str(len(cnt))+'\n' + str()

Comment: @AndreyZhuravlev, вы можете привести небольшие примеры `scores` и `classes` (по 2-3 строки)?

Comment: Для Scores 
0.8198966  0.40732923 0.2924264
Для classes
1.  1. 63.

Comment: @AndreyZhuravlev, т.е. оба являются одномерными векторами? Что показывает `print(classes.shape)`?

Comment: показывает (1, 100)

Comment: @AndreyZhuravlev, не понял последний комментарий...

Comment: Данный метод у меня работает. но не корректно, алгоритм не досчитывает 1-го "person", т.е. если на изображении 3 человека, он выводит 2, если 1 человек, то 0.

Comment: @AndreyZhuravlev, для того, чтобы иметь возможность разобраться с этим мне понадобится доступ к данным, при помощи которых можно воспроизвести данную проблему...

Comment: Для воспроизведения проблемы можно использовать любой доступный видеофайл, на котором есть люди или использовать веб-камеру, достаточно изменить cap = cv2.VideoCapture('output.mp4') на cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)