# Изменить формат вывода данных

Tags: python

Подскажите как изменить формат вывода данных. Есть код он здесь: [Распознавание объектов объектов на видео. Определять только класс "person" ghb](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/879856/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BE-%D0%9E%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81-person-ghb/879917#879917)

Изменил строку:

```
cnt = [category_index.get(value)for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if 
scores[0,index] > 0.5]
```

На:

```
cnt2 = [category_index.get(value)for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) 
if scores[0,index] > 0.5 and category_index.get(value).get('name') == 
'person']
```

Теперь корректно определяются только объекты типа "person" (человек) и  выводятся в `print()`.

Но столкнулся с проблемой. Теперь данные не являются числовым значением, а  выводятся в формате:

```
[{'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'person'}]
```

Почему так? И как сделать так чтобы данные опять корректно считались?

Comment: Почему это `Теперь данные не являются числовым значением`? Формат данных в исходном коде и в вашем одинаковый. А числовое значение, вы это про `str(len(cnt))` из оригинального кода?

Comment: @gil9red Блин....точно!...Видимо удалил. Благодарю, сэр.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Взял на себя смелость перенести часть кода из ссылки в вопросе:

```
cnt2 = [category_index.get(value)for index,value in enumerate(classes[0]) if scores[0,index] > 0.5 and category_index.get(value).get('name') == 'person']
cv2.putText(image_np,"Object detect= "+str(len(cnt2)) ,(10,25), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (0,0,0), 2)

cv2.imshow('image',cv2.resize(image_np,(640,480)))       
text_for_file = "Object detect= "+str(len(cnt2))+'\n'
...
```

Comment: Это для того, чтобы вопрос не висел без ответа